# spring security redis token store in clustered redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to deploy a spring-security server, with Redis as token store. 
In order to have some redundancy in Redis, we want to deploy it as a cluster.
The problem is Jedis, which is used by spring security as underlying library, doesn't support pipelining in cluster mode, but spring security uses pipelining.
My question is how can I solve this situation. More precisely:

1- Should I use another mode of deployment form Redis? What actually works.
2- Can I somehow force spring security to use reddison for connecting to Resid?

Please adivse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want redundancy, use replication (master/slave) not cluster.

If you have more data than RAM on a machine, use cluster.

If you have more data than RAM on a machine and want redundancy, use cluster with replication.

Jedis supports replication with sentinel, so give that a go unless you have a lot of data. Some more info on usage here: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/issues/725